# How to store and fetch data on iphone locally

Tags: iphone, cordova

What I want is:

1. Store data in iphone.
2. Display stored data.

Can I know simple way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you had the `[phonegap]` tag there. If you're not working with Objective C, I'll delete my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[iPhone SDK Tutorial: Reading data from a SQLite Database](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) and [12 SQLite Resources for iPhone Developers](http://mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to just serializing objects and storing them as files, I think the *easiest* (not the best ofcourse) way would be to do just write to a file on disk. (Cusomize as needed, this is a basic routine which assumes a lot of things like key being unique etc.) -

```
-(BOOL) setObjectWithKey:(NSString *) key andValue:(NSString *) value {
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:value forKey:key];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath:key] atomically:YES];
    [archiver release];
    [data release];
    return YES;
}
-(void) removeObjectFor:(NSString *) key
{
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL exists = [fm fileExistsAtPath:[self dataFilePath:key]];
    if (exists == YES) {
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[self dataFilePath:key] error:NULL];
    }
    return;
}
```

The Object above can actually be any Data model of yours (instead of a plain NSString) consisting of default Foundation Objects like NSStrings, ints etc. In which case, you have to implement some serialization code in your model object. Refer NSCoding, NSCopying.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you trying to store?

For very basic needs I've used localStorage. It probably wouldn't be good for a lot of data, but can be easily used to access smaller portions of data.

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value)
localStorage.getItem(key) //returns value associated with this key
```

To store more info you could possibly write to and read from a local file using fileWriter and fileReader if you want to implement it using javascript on the phonegap side of things. Just look at the [phonegap api](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html).